# Fix point of squaring numbers mod p

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, fixed-point-theorems

Take the set of integers $\{0, 1, .., p-1\}$, square each element, you get the (smaller) set of quadratic residues. Repeat until you get a fix point set. The size of this set is a function of $p$. Does this function have a name? How can I efficiently calculate it?

Some values:
$$f(3) = 2, \\
f(5) = 2,\\
f(7) = 4,\\
f(11) = 6,\\
f(13) = 4,  \\
f(17) = 2,\\
f(19) = 10,\\
f(23) = 12,\\
f(29) = 8$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us factor $p-1=2^am$, where $m$ is odd. The size of your terminal set is $m$.
You are working with a cyclic group of order $p-1$. As $m$ is odd, the Chinese Remainder Theorem tells you that there is an isomorphism
$$
\mathbb{Z}_p^*\cong C_m\times C_{2^a}.
$$
Repeated squaring kills the $C_{2^a}$ after $a$ iterations, and squaring is bijective on $C_m$.

If you include $0$ (I didn't), then add one.

Comment: There seems to be a difference of $1$, cf. OP's examples. Maybe from $x=0$?

Comment: Great! Thanks! I will accept this in 9 minutes ;)

Comment: @aelguindy: Sorry about not reading carefully enough, so I missed zero initially. Basically you just take $p-1$ and keep dividing it with two as many times as it takes to make the quotient odd. No need to fully factorize.

Comment: No worries! All that I figured out myself. I just needed to see $\mathbb{Z}_p^* \cong C_m \times C_{2^a}$ ;). Thanks again!