# Proving the two sets are equal whose elements are in finite fields.

Tags: finite-fields

Proving that $\{x\in GF(2^k)^{*}:tr^k_1(1/x)=1\}=\{u+u^{2^k}:u\in U\setminus\{1\}\}$,

where $tr^k_1(x)=x+x^{2^1}+x^{2^{2}}+ \dots+x^{2^{n-1}} $  is a trace function in finite fields and $U=\{u\in GF(2^{2k}):u^{2^k+1}=1\}$.

Given $u\in GF(2^{2k})\setminus GF(2^k)$, we can get the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $GF(2^k)$ is $f(x)=(x+u)(x+u^{2^k})=x^2+(u+u^{2^k})x+1$ if $u\in U$,  I'm not sure there is a method to get $tr^k_1(1/x)$ with above equation.Or I did a wrong attempt?

Comment: Describe what you have done so far to tackle this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following argument works. To save keystrokes I introduce the following notation:

- $F=GF(2^k)=\Bbb{F}_{2^k}$.
- $E=GF(2^{2k})=\Bbb{F}_{2^{2k}}$, the quadratic extension of $F$.
- If $z\in E$, I will denote its only $F$-conjugate $\overline{z}=z^{2^k}$. The mapping $\sigma:z\mapsto\overline{z}$ is the only non-identity automorphism of $E$ that maps elements of $F$ to themselves. It has order two, in other words $\overline{\overline{z}}=z$ for all $z\in E$.

I need the following basic facts.

**Fact 1.** $U$ consists of elements of the form $u(z):=z/\overline{z}$ with $z$ ranging over $E\setminus F$.

**Proof.** The equation $u^{2^k+1}=1$ is equivalent to $u^{2^k}=1/u$. In other words,
$u\in U$ if and only if $\overline{u}=1/u$. As $\sigma$ has order two, we immediately see that $\sigma(u(z))=\sigma(z)/\sigma(\overline{z})=\overline{z}/z=1/u(z)$. Therefore $u(z)\in U$. Clearly $u(z)=1$ if and only if $\overline{z}=z$ if and only if $z\in F$.

For the other inclusion let $g$ be a generator of the multiplicative group $E^*$, i.e. and element of order $2^{2k}-1=(2^k-1)(2^k+1)$. Then
$$u(g)=g/g^{2^k}=(1/g)^{2^k-1}$$ will be of order $2^k+1$. In other words, $u(g)$ generaters the multiplicative subgroup $U\cup\{1\}$ of $E^*$. As $u(g^j)=u(g)^j$ it follows that all the elements of $U$ are of the form $u(g^j)$. **QED.**

**Fact 2.** If $a\in F$ then the roots of the polynomial $f(T)=T^2+aT+b\in F[T], a\neq0,$ are elements of $F$ if $tr(b/a^2)=0$ and elements of $E\setminus F$ if $tr(b/a^2)=1$.

**Proof.** This is well known. Ask, if you need help here. **QED.**

All is set for the proof of the main claim. Assume first that $u\in U$. By the first fact we know that $u=z/\overline{z}$ for some $z\in E\setminus F$. Here
$$
x=u+u^{2^k}=u+\overline{u}=\frac{z}{\overline{z}}+\frac{\overline{z}}{z}
=\frac{(z+\overline z)^2}{z\overline{z}},
$$
where in the last step I used Freshman's dream. As in your minimal polynomial calculation, we see that $z$ and $\overline{z}$ are zeros of the polynomial (with coefficients from $F$)
$$
(T+z)(T+\overline{z})=T^2+(z+\overline{z})T+z\overline{z}=0.
$$
Here $z,\overline{z}\in E\setminus F$, so by Fact 2. we can deduce that
$$
1=tr(\frac{z\overline{z}}{(z+\overline{z})^2})=tr(\frac1x)
$$
proving one inclusion.

To get the other inclusion let's start with an element $x\in F^*$ such that $tr(1/x)=1$. By Fact 2. it follows that the zeros of the polynomial
$$
T^2+T+\frac1x=0\qquad(*)
$$
are elements of $E\setminus F$. Let $z$ be one of those zeros, the other is then $\overline{z}$. By Vieta relations we know that
$$
z+\overline{z}=1,\qquad\text{and}\qquad z\overline{z}=\frac1x.
$$
Reverting the above calculation, it follows that with $u=u(z)=z/\overline{z}\in U$ we have
$$
u+u^{-1}=\frac{(z+\overline{z})^2}{z\overline{z}}=\frac{1}{1/x}=x
$$
giving us the converse inclusion. **QED.**

---

There may be something simpler out there, but the above argument flows IMHO quite naturally with basic tricks of the trade in place. An alternative I came up with first was to use another parametrization for the set $U$ mentioned in [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104838/11619). There $U$ was denoted by $S$, and the parametrization would have been
$$U=\left\{\frac{x+z}{x+\overline{z}}\mid x\in F\right\},$$
where $z$ is a fixed element from $E\setminus F$. The details of the resulting calculation were in my opinion a bit less natural with that parametrization.